# Coefficient plot in GJRM

Tags: r, plot

I'm running a bivariate logit model and need to get the coefficient plots and substantive effects. However, it seems that the SemiParBIV object is not supported by all packages for marginial effects plotting. I use ggplot like this, but I can't extract the standard errors

```
# Create the coefficient plot
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = estimate, fill = model)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)) +
  labs(title = "Coefficient plot", x = "Variables", y = "Estimates")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.